# On what day was the Passover lamb slaughtered?

Tags: luke, contradiction, numbers, passover

Luke 22:7 (KJV) shows that passover was a single day:

> Then came the day of unleavened bread, ***when the passover must be killed.***

While Numbers lists the passover as a weeklong event:

Numbers 28:16-17 (KJV)

> <sup>16</sup> And in the fourteenth day of the first month is the passover of the LORD. <sup>17</sup> And in the fifteenth day of this month is the feast:  seven days shall unleavened bread be eaten

What is the reason for this difference? Was the passover celebration shortened over time or is it in fact a week long? If so what was the reason for the change or discrepancy?

Finally, on what day of passover was the lamb to be slaughtered (first, last or some other day?)

Comment: Collen,  Instead of posting numerous questions with the title "How can we reconcile X and Y" Summarize you actual question or problem. This will help with two things: First your questions are often closed because we aren't quite sure how or why you see a conflict. A better title will force you to focus your question and help us to better understand what you are asking.

Second, and more importantly, this question had the potential to be lost. I went back to edit the title and couldn't find it. By providing a better title, it makes the content more searchable and this will get you more UVs.

Comment: The plot becomes a bit clearer if we read: “then came he days for the feast of unleavened bread”, instead of “then came the day for the feast of unleavened bread”. The translated word “day” can apparently mean “days” also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Israelites were commanded to kill the Passover lamb **and** eat unleavened bread at twilight on the fourteenth:

> <sup>1</sup> Now the Lord spoke to Moses and Aaron in the land of Egypt, saying, <sup>2</sup> “This month shall be your beginning of months; it shall be the first month of the year to you. <sup>3</sup> Speak to all the congregation of Israel, saying: ‘On the tenth of this month every man shall take for himself a lamb, according to the house of his father, a lamb for a household. [...] <sup>6</sup> **Now you shall keep it until the fourteenth day of the same month. Then the whole assembly of the congregation of Israel shall kill it at twilight**. [...]  <sup>8</sup> Then they shall eat the flesh on that night; roasted in fire, **with unleavened bread** and with bitter herbs they shall eat it. [...] <sup>11</sup> And thus you shall eat it: with a belt on your waist, your sandals on your feet, and your staff in your hand. So you shall eat it in haste. **It is the Lord’s Passover**. [...] <sup>18</sup> In the first month, **on the fourteenth day of the month at evening, you shall eat unleavened bread**, until the twenty-first day of the month at evening.’”
>   [-Exodus 12:1-3, 6, 8, 11, 18 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus+12%3A1-20&version=NKJV)

Since unleavened bread was also eaten on the fourteenth, it is not unusual to find the fourteenth being referred to as the “the Day of Unleavened Bread, when the Passover must be killed.”

The Passover itself was a singular event that occurred right before the Feast of Unleavened Bread:

> <sup>5</sup> On the fourteenth day of the first month at twilight is the Lord’s Passover. <sup>6</sup> And on the fifteenth day of the same month is the Feast of Unleavened Bread to the Lord; seven days you must eat unleavened bread.
>   [-Leviticus 23:5-6 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus+23%3A5-6&version=NKJV)
>
> ---
>
> but at the place where the Lord your God chooses to make His name abide, there **you shall sacrifice the Passover at twilight, at the going down of the sun**, at the time you came out of Egypt.
>   [-Deuteronomy 16:6 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy+16%3A6&version=NKJV)

- Twilight on the fourteenth marked the the Passover. The lamb was killed in the evening at the going down of the sun, and unleavened bread was also eaten during this time.
- The fifteenth arrived after the sun had fully gone down, which began the Feast of Unleavened Bread.

These two events are intertwined and there is such a short time between them that it is not uncommon to say something such as “then came the Day of Unleavened Bread, when the Passover was to be killed,” especially since unleavened bread was eaten at the same time as the Passover lamb.

Answer (score 3):

The Passover is the 14th day of the month:

> In the first month, on the fourteenth day of the month at twilight, is the LORD’S Passover. (Leviticus 23:5) [ESV throughout]
>
> and you shall keep it until the fourteenth day of this month, when the whole assembly of the congregation of Israel shall kill their lambs at twilight. (Exodus 12:6)
>   This day shall be for you a memorial day, and you shall keep it as a feast to the Lord; throughout your generations, as a statute forever, you shall keep it as a feast. (Exodus 12:14)

Passover and the Feast of Unleavened Bread are separate events:

> In the first month, on the fourteenth day of the month at twilight, is the LORD’S Passover. And on the fifteenth day of the same month is the Feast of Unleavened Bread to the LORD; for seven days you shall eat unleavened bread. On the first day you shall have a holy convocation; you shall not do any ordinary work. But you shall present a food offering to the LORD or seven days. On the seventh day is a holy convocation; you shall not do any ordinary work.”
>    (Leviticus 23:5-8)

Numbers describes the additional offerings which are to be made during the Passover and Feast of Unleavened Bread:

> “On the fourteenth day of the first month is the LORD's Passover, and on the fifteenth day of this month is a feast. Seven days shall unleavened bread be eaten. (Numbers 28:16-17)

The two periods are distinct: Passover as a 1-day event on the 14th day of the month and the 7-days of unleavened bread follow. Nili S. Fox notes:

> The holy day on which the Passover sacrifice ("pesah") is offered is distinct from the seven-day Festival of Unleavened Bread ("matzot"); in other words, we have a festival complex of an evening festival (Pesah) followed immediately by a seven-day Matzot festival. <sup>1</sup>

While the two are separate, it was and still is the custom to refer to “Passover” as the period of time including both, as Luke states:

> Now the Feast of Unleavened Bread drew near, which is called the Passover. (Luke 22:1)

This custom is rooted in how the command to observe the Passover and Unleavened Bread is stated in Deuteronomy. Bernard M. Levenson explains:

> The blend of Passover and the Festival of Unleavened Bread is the most remarkable section of this calendar. Passover was originally a separate observance, celebrated within the family or clan. Since it did not require a sacrifice at the sanctuary, it was not included among the three pilgrimage festivals…But Deuteronomy’s restriction of sacrifice to the single sanctuary prohibited Passover from being observed locally (v.5) and required that the observance be redirected to the central sanctuary (vv.2,6-7)…The new observance then merges with the Festival of Unleavened Bread… <sup>2</sup>

Deuteronomy lacks any mention of the day of the month the Passover is to be sacrificed:

> “Observe the month of Abib and keep the Passover to the LORD your God, for in the month of Abib the LORD your God brought you out of Egypt by night. And you shall offer the Passover sacrifice to the LORD your God, from the flock or the herd, at the place that the LORD will choose, to make his name dwell there. You shall eat no leavened bread with it. Seven days you shall eat it with unleavened bread, the bread of affliction—for you came out of the land of Egypt in haste—that all the days of your life you may remember the day when you came out of the land of Egypt. No leaven shall be seen with you in all your territory for seven days, nor shall any of the flesh that you sacrifice on the evening of the first day remain all night until morning. You may not offer the Passover sacrifice within any of your towns that the LORD your God is giving you, but at the place that the LORD your God will choose, to make his name dwell in it, there you shall offer the Passover sacrifice, in the evening at sunset, at the time you came out of Egypt. And you shall cook it and eat it at the place that the LORD your God will choose. And in the morning you shall turn and go to your tents. For six days you shall eat unleavened bread, and on the seventh day there shall be a solemn assembly to the LORD your God. You shall do no work on it. (Deuteronomy 16:1-8)

The requirement to offer the sacrifice at the sanctuary does not interfere with the requirement to keep the feast. The Passover is observed today despite the lack of either the sanctuary or the Temple. The Passover sacrifice is not made; yet the remembrance meal is still observed.

Passover is a single day on the 14th and the Feast of Unleavened Bread is a seven day period from the 15th to the 21st. There were additional requirements regarding unleavened bread and leaven covering the combined 8-day period:

> In the first month, from the fourteenth day of the month at evening, you shall eat unleavened bread until the twenty-first day of the month at evening. For seven days no leaven is to be found in your houses. If anyone eats what is leavened... (Exodus 12:18-19)

Unleavened bread was also to be eaten on the 14th of the month, the day of the Passover. Leaven was to be removed from the house and not to be eaten in any food. Thus the Feast of Unleavened Bread is a 7-day period of eating unleavened bread, avoiding all foods with leaven, and keeping the house free from leaven.

The presence of leaven during the 7-days was unlawful and required the house to be clean beforehand. The current tradition is called Bedikat Chametz which is the search for leaven performed on the Passover eve (the 13th). The Babylonian Talmud states the leaven should be removed at night on the 14th (night is the beginning of the day). [[Babylonian Talmud 17a]](https://halakhah.com/berakoth/berakoth_17.html)  Removing leaven was a requirement to prepare for the Passover period.

Luke identifies the “day” (singular) of unleaveneds (plural):

> Then came the day of Unleavened Bread (ἡμέρα τῶν ἀζύμων - literally "day of unleaveneds"), on which the Passover lamb had to be sacrificed. (22:7)

Day is singular and does not mean the “Days” of Unleavened Bread. This singular day of unleavened bread would be the 14th of month, the day on which the house is to be free of leaven, unleavened bread is to be eaten, and the Passover is sacrificed.

Luke 22:1 and 22:7 can be combined to show the New Testament terminology and compared to the Old Testament calendar:
[image]
Based on the Gospel narratives, Jesus and His disciples ate the Last Supper at night, on the beginning of the 14th day (the memorial day). After eating He was arrested, tried, and crucified during the daylight and died on the 14th, the Old Testament day of the LORD’s Passover.

### Addendum

There is extra-Biblical evidence to support the crucifixion taking place on the eve of the Passover:

> 33...On the eve of the Passover Yeshu 34 was hanged. For forty days before the execution took place, a herald went forth and cried, 'He is going forth to be stoned because he has practised sorcery and enticed Israel to apostacy. Any one who can say anything in his favour, let him come forward and plead on his behalf.' But since nothing was brought forward in his favour he was hanged on the eve of the Passover! [[Babylonian Talmud Sanhedrin 43a]](https://juchre.org/talmud/sanhedrin/sanhedrin3.htm#43a)

---

<sub>Note:

1. Nili S. Fox, *The Jewish Study Bible*. Jewish Publication Society, 2004, p. 341

2. Bernard M. Levenson, *The Jewish Study Bible*. Jewish Publication Society, 2004, p. 401</sub>

Comment: The main thing keeping me from removing my downvote is the part where you say that based on the gospel narratives Jesus died on the 14th. Luke 22:7-13 has Jesus telling Peter & John where to prepare to eat the Passover, & Luke 22:15 has Jesus saying to the disciples that He has been desiring to eat this Passover with them. Similar events are described in Matt 26:17-19 and Mark 14:12-16. An argument for the 14th could be made from John's gospel, but not from the synoptic gospels (though perhaps this subject would be better addressed in another question).

Comment: Did you read the passages I referenced? Matthew 26:17, Mark 14:12, & Luke 22:7 all say it was the day of unleavened bread. Matthew & Mark both say that evening came **after** the disciples went into the city & found the man & prepared the room (Matthew 26:18-20; Mark 14:13-17). This means it was daylight while they were preparing. That, combined with the fact they were preparing to eat the Passover, with Jesus specifically saying "I have desired to eat this Passover with you before I suffer..." (Luke 22:15), means that Jesus dying on the 14th cannot be defended from the synoptic gospels.

Comment: What was unclear from my previous comments?

Comment: If the Passover lamb is killed on the evening of 14th, and Jesus told His disciples he has desired to eat this Passover with them before He suffers, then that only leaves the 15th for His death. I'm not sure how me saying "Jesus did not die on the 14th" could be taken any other way. If you can show otherwise then I will admit I was wrong, but this answer doesn't do that.

Comment: Link to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60871/on-what-day-was-the-passover-lamb-slaughtered) where this is discussed further.

Comment: I don't really think that Talmud reference can be used to prove anything other than someone named "Yeshu" was executed; which, I might add, was an extremely common name. Did you read the next paragraph? It goes on to say that "Yeshu" only had 5 disciples, and only 1 of the names is close to Jesus of Nazareth's actual disciple's name (Matthai). See [here](http://www.angelfire.com/mt/talmud/jesusnarr.html) for more problems. All in all, the Talmud is not a reliable source of information concerning Jesus of Nazareth.

Comment: @Boom Given the Talmud was put into writing between 200-500 AD, it defies logic to think the Yeshu of the Talmud who led Israel into apostasy was just another Yeshu and not Yeshu of Nazareth. The point is executions were carried out the day before Passover, as is stated in John. And there is a way to understand the Synoptics to arrive at the same conclusion.

Comment: I think that the only thing that "defies logic" is that you think that Talmud passage helps your case. There was no herald who cried out for 40 days before Jesus of Nazareth was crucified; Jesus had more than 5 disciples; and Jesus did not have any connections with the government, which is a part you quite conveniently left out of your quotation.

Comment: Reading over your answer again, I'm not even sure why you included a lot of the information you did because Collen's question didn't even ask when Jesus ate the last supper, or when he was arrested, or when he was crucified. The only other thing I can offer is an unfortunate down vote, since this answer is overall not really useful.

Answer (score 2):

This guy, SLM , nails it!!

“ There has been a transition over the centuries about Passover. Originally in Egypt and centuries thereafter, at sunset between the evenings of the 13th and 14th, they slew the lamb. Sunset marks the change of day. They slew it as the sun dipped into the horizon on the 14th. They applied the blood on the 14th. They ate it that night of the 14th. The death angel came through this night of the 14th. If any lamb was left till morning, they were to burn it on the 14th. They left Egypt by night of the 15th (Deut. 16:1; IOW, this too makes clear that the Passover was slain and eaten on the 14th; they can't eat and leave on the 15th at night, yet burn leftover lamb by the morning of the 14th per the command).

Num. 28:16-25 is a reiteration of Ex. 12:6-20. The 14th is Passover. The 15th to 21st is Feast of Unleavened Bread.

As mentioned, centuries later the two observances became conflated because there are too many people for too few priests (2 Chrn. 35:14). This framework was picked up and "codified" in the very influential Book of Jubilees written circa 200 BCE and was observed by nearly all in Christ's time. They went from slay in the evening and eat on the 14th at night to slay on the afternoon of the 14th and eat on the 15th at night.

That latter framework is what you read as it is translated in Luke 22:7 (slay in the end of the 14th as part of the unleavened bread feast combined). There is, however, another way to understand the translations that harmonizes the gospel accounts in keeping with how Christ and the disciples observed the Passover some 2,000 years ago. They slew and ate on the 14th.

Believe that addresses all of your questions.”

Everything about the Passover is done in haste. The lamb was killed just as the 13th day ended (at sunset, say 6pm) and the darkness of the new 14th day overtook the light of the sunset (in between the twilight). The lamb was prepared and cooked in haste and eaten maybe around 9pm. The destroyer came at midnight. No one could sleep for the cries of the Egyptians. The remnants of the lamb were burned at first light 6am when the Hebrews were then permitted to leave their homes.
This scenario in completely in line with the act of the last supper as well.

Here is my reinterpretation from the ancient Hebrew of Exodus 12:6:

March 24, 2021

EXODUS 12:6

Let it be established that it (the lamb) shall be corralled and safeguarded to the point at which the 14th day of the month is even at its door.  At the head, or beginning, of this day shall the entire house of Israel and the descendants thereof and the entire house of Jacob and his descendants come together to slay it.  This shall always be done at twilight at that point in between the two days where the darkness is mingled with the Sunset.

NOTE:
This means that the Passover lamb shall be killed at twilight between the 13th day of the month and the 14th day of the month. Ideally, at the precise moment at which the darkness of the 14th day has overtaken the light of the 13th day at its Sunset.

Comment: Welcome to BH. Up-voted +1.

Answer (score 1):

There has been a transition over the centuries about Passover.  Originally in Egypt and centuries thereafter, at sunset between the evenings of the 13th and 14th, they slew the lamb.  Sunset marks the change of day.  They slew it as the sun dipped into the horizon on the 14th.  They applied the blood on the 14th.  They ate it that night of the 14th.  The death angel came through this night of the 14th.  If any lamb was left till morning, they were to burn it on the 14th.  They left Egypt by night of the 15th (Deut. 16:1; IOW, this too makes clear that the Passover was slain and eaten on the 14th; they can't eat and leave on the 15th at night, yet burn leftover lamb by the morning of the 14th per the command).

Num. 28:16-25 is a reiteration of Ex. 12:6-20.  The 14th is Passover.  The 15th to 21st is Feast of Unleavened Bread.

As mentioned, centuries later the two observances became conflated because there are too many people for too few priests (2 Chrn. 35:14).  This framework was picked up and "codified" in the very influential Book of Jubilees written circa 200 BCE and was observed by nearly all in Christ's time.  They went from slay in the evening and eat on the 14th at night to slay on the afternoon of the 14th and eat on the 15th at night.

That latter framework is what you read as it is translated in Luke 22:7 (slay in the end of the 14th as part of the unleavened bread feast combined).  There is, however, another way to understand the translations that harmonizes the gospel accounts in keeping with how Christ and the disciples observed the Passover some 2,000 years ago.  They slew and ate on the 14th.

Believe that addresses all of your questions.

Comment: is there anyone else (another author) that agrees with your timeline? This is the only timeline that has fit my mind since I started to seek for info about the jewish calendar. Nevertheless, you are the first person that I have seen to hold and sustainably explain your position. I'd really like to have some more fundaments to consolidate this timeline to the church I attend to.

Comment: You would have to look at certain of the various church fathers, like Polycarp, Polycrates, Melito for a start.  Basically the quartodecimans (4 and 10 or 14), those who believed Christ was crucified on the 14th.  The Book of Jubilees (Passover at sunset as the 14th ends and the 15th begins as the "best answer chosen" shows) traces to Philo and Josephus and then to Rome.  And now to the "best answer".  I've a 200 page unpublished manuscript looking for a publisher on these things.

Answer (score 1):

## What is meant by “Passover” (in the Bible)?

A number of people are confused by the use of the word 'Passover'. The question is often asked, “When is Passover?” And often it is answered with a simple date. However, the biblical use of the word suggests a more complex meaning, and a single date is therefore an inadequate answer. Understanding the proper use of this word is essential in the study to know whether Jesus ate the Passover on the night before he was killed.

In the early verses of Exodus 12, God introduces the Passover.  I have reproduced the King James text here, but I've added back the noun for all the pronouns used, to help indicate what God is telling us throughout this passage.

### The Passover as the Lamb

> **Exodus 12:3-11** –
> ¶Speak ye unto all the congregation of Israel, saying, In the tenth
> day of this month they shall take to them every man a lamb, according
> to the house of their fathers, a lamb for an house: 4 And if the
> household be too little for the lamb, let him and his neighbour next
> unto his house take it [the lamb] according to the number of the
> souls; every man according to his eating shall make your count for the
> lamb.  5 Your lamb shall be without blemish, a male of the first year:
> ye shall take it [the lamb] out from the sheep, or from the goats:  6
> And ye shall keep it [the lamb] up until the fourteenth day of the
> same month: and the whole assembly of the congregation of Israel shall
> kill it [the lamb] in the evening [between the two evenings].  7 And
> they shall take of the blood, and strike it [the blood of the lamb] on
> the two side posts and on the upper door post of the houses, wherein
> they shall eat it [the lamb].  8 And they shall eat the flesh [of the
> lamb] in that night, roast with fire, and unleavened bread; and with
> bitter herbs they shall eat it [the lamb].  9 Eat not of it [the lamb]
> raw, nor sodden at all with water, but roast with fire; his [the
> lamb's] head with his [the lamb's] legs, and with the purtenance
> thereof.  10 And ye shall let nothing of it [the lamb] remain until
> the morning; and that which remaineth of it [the lamb] until the
> morning ye shall burn with fire.  11 ¶And thus shall ye eat it [the
> lamb]; with your loins girded, your shoes on your feet, and your staff
> in your hand; and ye shall eat it [the lamb] in haste: it [the lamb]
> is the Lord's passover.

As we can see, the last line clearly defines what the Passover is—“it [the lamb] is the Lord's passover.”  That definition is reinforced later in the chapter:

> **Exodus 12:21** – ¶Then Moses called for all the elders of Israel, and
> said unto them, Draw out and take you a lamb according to your
> families, and kill the passover.

The lamb, selected and sacrificed at the specified time, is the Passover.

### The Passover as a Period of Time (“Between the Evenings”)

However, this definition does not hold in all uses of the word.  The following verses seem to include the rites of the Passover meal and the sacrifice, but is still emphasizing the lamb which is sacrificed.

> **Exodus 12:26-27** – And it shall come to pass, when your children shall
> say unto you, What mean ye by this service?  That ye shall say, It is
> the sacrifice of the Lord's passover, who passed over the houses of
> the children of Israel in Egypt, when he smote the Egyptians, and
> delivered our houses. And the people bowed the head and worshipped.

But yet again, when God specifies the Passover to the priesthood, he says:

> **Leviticus 23:5** – In the first month, on the fourteenth of the month,
> between the evenings is the Passover to Jehovah.

Here, it is the specific time period that is referred to as the Passover.

### The Passover as a Seven Day Feast

And it seems that the Feast of Unleavened Bread is also referred to as “The Passover”:

> **Exodus 34:25** – Thou shalt not offer the blood of my sacrifice with
> leaven; neither shall the sacrifice of the feast of the passover be
> left unto the morning.
>
> **Ezekiel 45:21** – In the first month, in the fourteenth day of the
> month, ye shall have the passover, a feast of seven days; unleavened
> bread shall be eaten.

Luke verifies this, when he states:

> **Luke 22:1** – Now the feast of unleavened bread drew nigh, which is
> called the Passover.

Many Bible scholars claim that this identity between the Passover (proper) and the Feast of Unleavened Bread came about over the years.  Thus the several references in the New Testament:

> **Matthew 26:2** – Ye know that  after two days is the feast of the
> passover, and the Son of man is betrayed to be crucified.
>
> **Mark 14:1** – After two days was the feast of the passover, and of
> unleavened bread: and the chief priests and the scribes sought how
> they might take him by craft, and put him to death.
>
> **Luke 2:41** – Now his parents went to Jerusalem every year at the feast
> of the passover.
>
> **John 6:4** – And the passover, a feast of the Jews, was nigh.
>
> **John 13:1** – Now before the feast of the passover, when Jesus knew that
> his hour was come that he should depart out of this world unto the
> Father, having loved his own which were in the world, he loved them
> unto the end.

However, let's read Exodus 12 a little more carefully.

> **Exodus 12:14** – This day shall be to you for a memorial, …

God seems to start out talking about the Passover as a day, but then switches to the seven day feast:

> 14 – … and you shall keep it a feast to Yahweh: throughout your
> generations you shall keep it a feast by an ordinance forever.
>
> 15 – “‘Seven days you shall eat unleavened bread; even the first day
> you shall put away yeast out of your houses, for whoever eats leavened
> bread from the first day until the seventh day, that soul shall be cut
> off from Israel.
>
> 16 – In the first day there shall be to you a holy convocation, and in
> the seventh day a holy convocation; no kind of work shall be done in
> them, except that which every man must eat, that only may be done by
> you.
>
> 17 – You shall observe the feast of unleavened bread; …

And then switches back to talking about the day:

> … for in this same day have I brought your armies out of the land of
> Egypt: therefore you shall observe this day throughout your
> generations by an ordinance forever.

Then back to the feast again:

> 18 – In the first month, on the fourteenth day of the month at
> evening, you shall eat unleavened bread, until the twenty first day of
> the month at evening.
>
> 19 – There shall be no yeast found in your houses for seven days, for
> whoever eats that which is leavened, that soul shall be cut off from
> the congregation of Israel, whether he be a foreigner, or one who is
> born in the land.
>
> 20 – You shall eat nothing leavened. In all your habitations you shall
> eat unleavened bread.’”

So, where do the Feast of Unleavened Bread and the Passover first get intertwined and identified together? It is from God's own words! God himself shows that the Passover and the Feast of Unleavened Bread are intimately connected.

Contrary to scholarly opinion (which is primarily based upon an ungodly and faulty premise of higher biblical criticism), the Passover and the Feast of Unleavened Bread were not two separate feasts (the merging of two cultural celebrations).  Unfortunately, some have been led astray by this faulty premise, and thus read Leviticus 23:5-6 as if the 14th day is the Passover “feast” and the 15th day begins a separate feast. The Word of God simply does not support that interpretation. Rather, Leviticus 23:6 should be read as the festival portion of the Passover, the beginning of the Feast of the Passover.

Thus, and once again, “the Passover” refers to a period of time, but one more extended than the few hours during which the lamb is to be sacrificed, as first suggested.

### The Passover as a Complete Package

> **Numbers 9:3 (LITV)** – In the fourteenth day of this month, between the
> evenings, you shall prepare it according to all its statutes, and
> according to all its ordinances.

Thus, when God says, “keep it in its appointed season—according to all its statutes, and according to all its ordinances” (Numbers 9:3), included in those ordinances is: the selection on the 10 th day, the sacrifice on the 14th day, the meal on the night of the 15th, and the seven day Feast of Unleavened Bread with its Sabbaths (High Days) from the 15th to the 21st inclusive. That is why we see in II Chronicles 30:13 the Feast was kept in the second month along with the Passover on the 14th day.

> **II Chronicles 30:13 (LITV)** – And many people gathered to Jerusalem, to
> keep the Feast of Unleavened Bread in the second month, a very great
> multitude.

It should be noted that the fourteenth day (as a whole) is never referred to as “the Passover”. However, in the New Testament, the Apostle John explicitly refers to the 14th day as “the Preparation of the Passover” (John 19:14). The other evangelists simply abbreviate it to “the Preparation [Day]” (Matthew 27:62; Mark 15:42; Luke 23:54).

The word 'passover' has several meanings in the Bible. We see that it initially meant the selected, unblemished lamb that was to be sacrificed at the appointed time. Its meaning also has the extended meaning of the time period in which the lamb is to be sacrificed ('between the evenings', which is between the ninth hour and sunset on the fourteenth day of the first month). It also referred to the entire Feast of Unleavened Bread. The specific meaning is usually evident from the context.

Most of the time the context is clear enough that we can determine which meaning is intended.  However, there are some crucial places where it is still rather vague.  Such as, what exactly did Jesus mean when he told Peter and John to “Go and prepare us the passover” (Luke 22:8)?  Was he referring to preparing the lamb?  Or the meal?  Or the Feast of Unleavened Bread?  Or something else?

## What is the Meaning of Mark 14:12 & Luke 22:7-8?

> **Mark 14:12** – And the first day of unleavened bread, when they killed the passover, his disciples said unto him, Where wilt thou that we go and prepare that thou mayest eat the passover?
>
> **Luke 22:7-8** – Then came the day of unleavened bread, when the passover must be killed. And he sent Peter and John, saying, Go and prepare us the passover, that we may eat.

What are Mark and Luke referring to here?

**“the first day of unleavened bread”, “the day of unleavened bread” –**
Strictly speaking, the first day of unleavened bread (Mark 14:12) would be Nisan/Abib 15 (Leviticus 23:6).  By extension, some have considered the day on which the Passover lamb is killed (the 14th day) to be the first day, and was also included as a day of unleavened bread (even though there was no requirement for the bread eaten on the 14th to be unleavened, only from the 15th through the 21st).  But depending upon the meaning of Matthew 26:20, this day could either still be the 13th or the beginning of the 14th.  But there is no way it could be the 15th.

However, claiming this time to be on the 14th also doesn't work, as it leads to a number of conflicts with other Gospel record evidence (examples: they could not be preparing the Passover at the same time that they were to eat it, nor could it be eaten beyond morning).

The Law is clear about when the Passover lamb was to be killed:

> **Exodus 12:6 (LITV)** – And it shall be for you to keep until the
> fourteenth day of this month. And all the assembly of the congregation
> of Israel shall kill it between the evenings.
>
> **Leviticus 23:5 (LITV)** – in the first month, on the fourteenth of the
> month, between the evenings, is the passover to Jehovah;
>
> **Numbers 9:3 (LITV)** – Also the sons of Israel shall prepare the
> Passover in its appointed season.  In the fourteenth day of this
> month, between the evenings, you shall prepare it according to all its
> statutes, and according to all its ordinances.  And Moses spoke to the
> sons of Israel to prepare the Passover.  And they prepared the
> Passover in the first month on the fourteenth day of the month,
> between the evenings, in the wilderness of Sinai, according to all
> that Jehovah had commanded Moses, so the sons of Israel did.

**“when they killed the passover”, “when the passover must be killed” –**
Some have interpreted this to indicate that the Passover lambs were being killed at that very moment by others.  However, as per above, it was not yet time to kill the Passover.

Kenneth S. Wuest, in his “The Gospels: An Expanded Translation”, has: “at which time it was the custom to kill the passover” (Mark XIV, 12-15, p. 156).  Introducing the notion of 'custom' helps clarify the meaning.  It was not referring to actions that were taking place at that moment, but to the continuing custom (annual event) of killing the Passover at its appointed time.  Though the time for killing the Passover had not yet arrived, it was imminent and it was time to make other preparations (such as, ready the room).  Also:

> **Luke 22:7 (The Peschito Syriac New Testament by J.W. Etheridge)** – And
> the day of unleavened bread came, on which it was the custom to slay
> the petscha.

The Passover was to be killed at its customary time—on the 14th day, between the evenings (between the ninth hour and sunset)—which would not arrive until Jesus was dying on the cross.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's take a look at the very first prescription of the Passover.

Exodus 12:6 (Young’s Literal Translation - YLT)

> And it hath become a charge to you, until the fourteenth day of this month and the whole assembly of the company of Israel have *slaughtered it between the evenings*;

Note that this verse says *between the evenings*. Regarding this verse in specific, it is important to mention some of the Jewish traditions practiced by Jesus and post Jesus' time. Some people believe that *between the evenings* means from noontime to sunset. Others believe that it means from the start of the sunset to the appearance of the 3 stars in the sky. Yet, some understand that it is the period between 3 pm to 6 pm (and I won’t get into details of what are the *two evenings* and all this non-pacific understanding of it, because it makes no difference in the current analysis).

Notwithstanding, the verse itself does not tell us the exact meaning of *evenings*.

Thus, in order to rationally figure it out, it’s imperious to (hermeneutically) scrutinize what the scriptures say about it.

First of all, it is demanded to check how the *day* was accountable (and I mean our 24h period named *day*, and not the “lightened period comprehended within 24h”)

So, let's start from the beginning of it all.

Genesis 1:1-4 (Young’s Literal Translation - YLT)

> 1 In the beginning of God's preparing the heavens and the earth --
> 2 the earth hath existed waste and void, and darkness [is] on the face of the deep, and the Spirit of God fluttering on the face of the waters, 3 and God saith, 'Let light be;' and light is.4 And God seeth the light that [it is] good, and God separateth between the light and the darkness, 5 and God calleth to the light 'Day', and to the darkness He hath called 'Night;' and there is an evening, and there is a morning -- day one.

From these verses, it is reasonable to infer that *evening* = unlightened period and *morning* =  lightened period, as for darkness (unlightened period) existed before light.

Notwithstanding, it is also suggestible that the opposite way around could also be true: that *morning* is the unlightened period and *evening* is the lightened period, because of the order of the words *day/night* that precedes the words *evening/morning*.

So it is reasonable to indague which one of them would be the most proper interpretation.

In order to solve this doubt, let's get back to the bible to scrutinize a fragment of Leviticus 23, where God himself from his own mouth prescribed to Moses how things should be done.

Leviticus 23:26-32 (YLT)

> (26) And Jehovah speaketh unto Moses, saying,
> (27) 'Only--on the tenth of this seventh month is a day of atonements; ye have a holy convocation, and ye have humbled yourselves, and have brought near a fire-offering to Jehovah; (28) and ye do no work in this self-same day, for it is a day of atonements, to make atonement for you, before Jehovah your God. (29) For any person who is not humbled in this self-same day hath even been cut off from his people; (30) and any person who doth any work in this self-same day I have even destroyed that person from the midst of his people; (31) ye do no work--a statute age-during to your generations in all your dwellings. (32) It [is] a sabbath of rest to you, and ye have humbled yourselves in the ninth of the month at even; from evening till evening ye do keep your sabbath.'

Now let's take a closer look at some verses declined just above:

> (27) 'Only--on *the tenth* of this seventh month is a day of atonement (...)
> (28) and ye do no work in this *self-same day* (...)
> (32) It [is] a sabbath of rest to you, and ye have humbled yourselves *in the ninth of the month at even; from evening till evening ye do keep your sabbath*.'

Note that the global analysis of these verses tell us that:

1. The Sabbath (the day of rest) is *day 10th*;
2. People must keep the rest *from evening til evening* which means that the sabbath is considered the period comprehended between evenings;
3. *Day 10th starts at even of day 9th*.

From these verses it is reasonable to conclude that:

1. Day 10th beginning at the end of day 9th;
2. Day 10th is accounted from the end of day 9th to the end of day 10th;
3. Day 10th starts at the sundown of day 9th;

So, the evening mentioned in Gn. 1:1-5 is the unenlightened period of the day (24h period). Said that the evening starts at sundown.

Thus, *from evening til evening* (which could also be inexorably expressed as *between evenings*) means from sunset to sunset.

Keep in mind that all the biblical texts mentioned until now are within the Pentateuch, so when God used to talk to people “face to face”.

Also, keep in mind that the Pentateuch dates back to similar periods, so there was not much room for human interpretation since God Himself prescribed His ordinances.

So you might be thinking: but why you have come to this conclusion?

The principle of the hierarchy of the law system says that general rules (or "principles," which have no immediate material applicability) should be a guideline to the provisions of rules prescribed in the context of specific laws. Thus, the rules of conduct must obligatorily maintain similarity to the general principle.

Furthermore, the principle of the hierarchy of laws also says that the specific provisions prevail over the more general ones, as long as they are credible, that is, they do not contradict generalist provisions and, obviously, are within the same context.

For this reason, is feasible to conclude that the expression *evening* or *between evenings* is the one mentioned above.

That said, let's take a look at the Passover command once more:

> Exodus 12:6 'And it hath become a charge to you, until the fourteenth day of this month, and the whole assembly of the company of Israel have *slaughtered it between the evenings*;

After all the analysis, it is reasonable to conclude that the expression *between the evenings* means *from sunset to sunset*, as it says on the 14th, so, *from the sunset of the 13th to the sunset of the 14th*.

Now, let's go to the practical part of the Passover comprehended within Lv.12, so to corroborate what was said by SLM.

There are a few other details that should be noted:

1. Passover was on the 14th;
2. They had to eat within the night time, before morning, and burn the leftovers that were not eaten til morning

Two things here: a) The YLT says “that which is remaining of it till morning with fire ye do burn”, which means that the leftover that was not eaten til morning should be burned at some point (not described), and not that it should be burned in the morning, or as the morning comes; b) Some translators have translated this peace as “til morning” and others have done it as “til tomorrow”. It doesn’t really matter which is the exact interpretation for the means of this analysis, but I thought it was important to provoke reasoning in readers.

3. The death passed over by midnight;
4. They had to “strip” the Egyptians (gold, precious things, etc) and pack it up (tents, flock, etc).
5. They left on the 15th during nighttime.

So, it doesn’t sound reasonable (thus, enforced) to say that all of it happened within one unlightened period.

As SLM said, the order of the happening was most probably as it follows:

1. Lambs slew started by the sunset of the 13th (namely, in the very first hours of the 14th);
2. They slew, reated and eat it all through the night comprehended between the twilight of 13th and the sunrise of the 14th;
3. Meanwhile, at midnight, the “angel of death” passed over and killed the firstborn;
4. The Egyptians cried out over this same night;
5. At some point after the sun rose (in the morning, or before tomorrow) they burned the leftovers;
6. They had the whole daylight period to strip the Egyptians and pack it all up, so, to prepare everything that was needed to run away (namely, it was the *preparation* day);
7. Then, they ran off from Egypt after the sunset of day 14th, thus, in the very beginning of the day 15th, during the unlightened part of day 15th (before sunrise);
8. Because they were running away, all they could eat was the unleveraged bread they cooked anticipatedly (1st day of the Mitza feast).

Then, what about at Jesus' time?

Many people (as Josephus) mention that the lambs were slew after noontime of the day 14th and eaten on the very first hours of day 15th.

Though, it was probably changed by tradition (read Mark 7:1-13), as God’s prescription doesn't leave any room to justify the lamb slew and the Seder between the 14th and 15th of Nisan.

I apologize for the long text, but I believe that it would be more didactic if it was done in detail.

Also, I know it is a “late response”, but as it happened with me (thanks SLM), perhaps other people might be after some info on this nowadays and in the coming future.

At last, sorry for my English mistakes, as it is not my native language.

I hope I have made it clear.

PS. I haven't been clear enough.
Passover is the Preparation day, namely, Nisan 14th. Period.
The lamb must be slew, roasted, and eaten within the 14th Nisan. From 15th to 21st is the unleavened bread feast (mitzvah). Yes, Luke refers to the Passover as it was part of the mitzvah feast, from the 14th to the 21st (as an 8-day feast), even though in Exodus it is cristal clear that Passover in the 14th. All of this is said in the above text (but about Luke's referral). Perhaps the question has been answered now.

Comment: Hi David, welcome to BH-Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here. Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://www.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read our [code of conduct](https://www.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/conduct). Thanks!

Comment: Hi Daniel, have I done something wrong??? I have read but, perhaps I have missed something. Please tell me whatever I did wrong.

Comment: Hello David. No nothing wrong done, all "new contributor" gets a message similar to this, to lead the new members to our site tour & code of conduct. the message was done solely because you are a new contributor and not based on the answer! God bless you David